# Use image from theme/image folder in twig template

Tags: twig, grav

I would like to include an image from `custom_theme/images` folder where `custom_theme` is a custom theme created following the grav documentation.

The *twig* template is in partials and this is the excerpt:

```
<!-- Logo -->
<a class="navbar-brand" href="./">
    <img class="logo logo-dark" alt="" src="/images/logo.png">
    <img class="logo logo-light" alt="" src="/images/logo-light.png">
</a>
<!-- #end Logo -->
```

What shall be used in `src` to refer to this image file: `/user/themes/custom_theme/images/logo.png`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you taken a look at the [Grav documentation](https://learn.getgrav.org/)? I typed "image" to the search field and found this:

> ### [Twig Filters & Functions](https://learn.getgrav.org/themes/twig-filters-functions)
>
> #### [Url](https://learn.getgrav.org/themes/twig-filters-functions#url)
>
> Will create a URL and convert any PHP URL streams into a valid HTML resources. A default value can be passed in in case the URL cannot be resolved.
>
> `url('theme://images/logo.png')|default('http://www.placehold.it/150x100/f4f4f4')` → **/user/themes/learn2/images/logo.png**

So you should probably have:

```
<!-- Logo -->
<a class="navbar-brand" href="./">
    <img class="logo logo-dark" alt="" src="{{ url('theme://images/logo.png') }}">
    <img class="logo logo-light" alt="" src="{{ url('theme://images/logo-light.png') }}">
</a>
<!-- #end Logo -->
```

If you want, you can use the basic [`default` Twig filter](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/filters/default.html) to provide a fallback URL if the image can't be found. If you don't use the `default` filter and the image can't be found, the `url` function will return nothing (or actually `null`, but it will be converted into an empty string), as can be seen in the [source code of the `url` function](https://github.com/getgrav/grav/blob/2f763809ac7d4a0a67e12d0522d4f90e9fcbb342/system/src/Grav/Common/Twig/TwigExtension.php#L659).

Comment: Thanks, in response to your answer yes I have taken a look, I went through `media` and `image linking` grav documentation sections.

Comment: No problem! Happy to help. I hope my question didn't come across as arrogant.

Comment: Not at all, I just wanted to point where I decided to look into.